# mesh dosent completely follow armature with 100% influence

Tags: bones, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

i am trying to get the other part of the shorts (i literally cannot think of a name for that part of the clothing) to be 100% influenced by the paint job i gave it but the mesh wont completely follow the bones. if the answer has anything to do with bone groups or vertex groups then please try to explain like im a child because i dont know anything about those things.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aHDLuepFCd2LKHM0I8pOOkKhHD7ZpEEj?usp=sharing)

[image: how to use the model]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some bones are hidden, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide in *Edit* mode. You'll see some huge bones (some are overlapping btw), and these bones have their *Deform* option enabled, so when you'll parent *With Automatic Weights* these bones will influence. I'm not sure what these bones are for, but I doubt they are useful or that their *Deform* option is useful. Also before you'll reparent, apply the rotation of your armature and objects (they are rotated).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found out the bone above it has a lot of influence on that part of the shorts model. removing the paint of the bone above on that part of the shorts did the trick